# Stream avi file while its generated on the fly ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mp4, rtmp, avi

Is possible to stream live an AVI File generated (continous writing from a third party app) and stream it to RTMP server with ffmpeg ?
**Software1:**
Continous write to AVI

**FFMPEG:**
Stream this AVI file to an RTMP server

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @szatmary How is this possible please ? WhenI try ffmpeg streams the AVI loaded in memory and stops. Thanks

Comment: @szatmary When I try to do it brokes with ffmpeg error "Unable to parse option value -1" as pixel format and "Error setting option pix_fmt to value -1"